# Find the highest value in a HashSet/ArrayList by a specific object attribute

Tags: java, collections, guava, apache-commons

I have a List of Car objects. Each car object has a type indicating whether its a sedan, suv, coupe, van or truck) along with other attributes. Assume my application ranks these in order listed below

- Sedan (lowest)
- Coupe
- Van
- SUV
- Truck  (highest)

How do I find the highest ranked type from among the list.

```
class Car {

 public Car (String type, String model, int year, long mileage){
     this.type=type;
     this.model = model;
     this.year = year;
     this.mileage = mileage;
 }

  private String type; // Sedan, SUV etc
  private String model; // Focus, Corolla, Camry, Taurus etc
  private int year; 
  private long mileage;

 //getters

}

List<Car> allCars = new ArrayList();
allCars.add(new Car("Coupe", "Focus", 1999, 50000) );
allCars.add(new Car("Sedan", "Camry", 2007, 60000) );
allCars.add(new Car("Truck", "Sierra", 2007, 50000) );
allCars.add(new Car("Truck", "F-150", 2001, 60000) );
allCars.add(new Car("Van", "Sienna", 1999, 40000) );
```

What is the most efficient way in Java 5 to find Truck (Cars with the highest ranked type). I can use apache commons api or guava, if required.

I can loop thru and create a set of unique types.

```
 Set<String> uniqueTypes = new HashSet<String>;
 for(Car car: allCars) {
     uniqueTypes.add(car.getType);
 }
```

Using the above Set, how can I find out the max (ie Truck in this example). Will Collections.max() return the max by natural order?

Comment: Make `type` an `enum`.

Comment: You need to use the `max` method with a `Comparator` and tell that how to order the items.

Answer (score 2):

First it helps to make the type of car an `enum` - this allows you to sort values more easily and adds type safety to the `Car` class.

The next step is to use the `max(Collection<? extends T> coll, Comparator<? super T> comp)` method in `Collections`.

You need to decide how to sort on the other values - when you have two cars of the same type. The default implementation will return the first highest value it comes across. You may want to do a secondary sort on, say, model if types are the same.

Here is an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    List<Car> allCars = new ArrayList();
    allCars.add(new Car(CarType.COUPE, "Focus", 1999, 50000));
    allCars.add(new Car(CarType.SEDAN, "Camry", 2007, 60000));
    allCars.add(new Car(CarType.TRUCK, "Sierra", 2007, 50000));
    allCars.add(new Car(CarType.TRUCK, "F-150", 2001, 60000));
    allCars.add(new Car(CarType.VAN, "Sienna", 1999, 40000));

    Car max = Collections.max(allCars, new Comparator<Car>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Car o1, Car o2) {
            return o1.getType().compareTo(o2.getType());
        }
    });
    System.out.println(max);
}

static class Car {

    public static enum CarType {

        SEDAN,
        COUPE,
        VAN,
        SUV,
        TRUCK;
    }
    private CarType type;
    private String model; // Focus, Corolla, Camry, Taurus etc
    private int year;
    private long mileage;

    public Car(CarType type, String model, int year, long mileage) {
        this.type = type;
        this.model = model;
        this.year = year;
        this.mileage = mileage;
    }
    //getters
    //toString
}
```

In this case `max` is the "Sierra" as it is the first truck in the list.

Alternatively you could use a `SortedSet` like a `TreeSet` but then you would need to be **very careful** with implementing the `Comparator` as it would need to be [consistent with equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) otherwise items that had the same rank but were not `equals` would simply be ignored.

**EDIT**

Example of using an `enum` internally but taking a `String` in the constructor:

```
static class Car {

    public static enum CarType {

        Sedan,
        Coupe,
        Van,
        SUV,
        Truck;
    }
    private CarType type;
    private String model; // Focus, Corolla, Camry, Taurus etc
    private int year;
    private long mileage;

    public Car(String type, String model, int year, long mileage) {
        this.type = CarType.valueOf(type);
        this.model = model;
        this.year = year;
        this.mileage = mileage;
    }
    //getters
    //toString
}
```

Comment: Thanks @bmorris591 for your example. In my case the CarTypes is an existing object used by many APIs and it might not be trivial to convert them to Enums. However, even with an Enum, where are you specifiying the order (that a VAN is ranked higher than the COUPE, SEDAN or the TRUCK is higher than all the rest).

Comment: You can make it an `enum` internally using `CarType.valueOf(String)` to parse the incoming `String` to a `CarType`. When enums are declared they are assigned an index, this index is their natural order - so the order they are declared in is the order they are sorted by. Maybe read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

Answer (score 2):

Although introducing CarType enum is a good way to do it, if you can't / don't want to change type to string you can use Guava's [`Ordering`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html) which is more powerful and polished fluent `Comparator` API. In your case use [`Ordering#explicit(T, T...)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#explicit%28T,%20T...%29):

```
final Car maxRank = Ordering.explicit("Sedan", "Coupe", "Van", "SUV", "Truck")
    .onResultOf(CarFunction.GET_TYPE)
    .max(allCars);
System.out.println(maxRank.getModel()); // Sierra
```

where `CarFunction.GET_TYPE` is defined as:

```
private enum CarFunction implements Function<Car, String> {
  GET_TYPE {
    @Override
    public String apply(final Car car) {
      return car.getType();
    }
  };
}
```

or as `private static final Function` or in Java 8 as lambda `c -> c.getType()`.

You can read more about Ordering on [this Wiki page](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/OrderingExplained).